# Return the first word in the image name

Tags: php, strings, url

I just want to return the first word in the image name (before the dash, `dog` in my example). Now I use it like this but believe it can be done in a simpler way (like one line of code):

```
$live_site_image = "http://example.net/wp-content/themes/example/images/dog-in-park.jpg";
$live_site_image = substr( strrchr( $live_site_image, '/' ), 1);
$live_site_image = strtok($live_site_image,"-");
```

Comment: Sure, you could put it all in one line, but do you really want to? It's much more readable this way than `$live_site_image = strtok(substr( strrchr( "http://example.net/wp-content/themes/example/images/dog-in-park.jpg", '/' ), 1),"-");` (ignore any spacing issues; it's hard to fix those in a comment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not convinced that your 2-liner is as horrible as you make it out to be. It is relatively clear, and well structured. Do you really want to go in to the realm of regular expressions for this? If you make your 2-liner a function it becomes even better:

```
$live_site_image = extractImage($live_site_image);
```

I think the intended 1-line solution using regex is to use `preg_replace` rather than what @janos suggests `preg_match`. With the replace, you can back-reference the matched group, and do it in one line:

```
$live_site_image = preg_replace('/.+\/([^.-]+).*/', '$1', $live_site_image);
```

Find forward until the last `/`, then take whatever comes after it until the next `.`, `-`, or end-of-line, and call that group 1. Then replace everything with group 1....

As an ideone here: http://ideone.com/NZWzpe

Answer (score 5):

If you want to *capture* part of a pattern,
you can use `preg_match`, and surround the pattern you want to capture in `(...)`,
like this:

```
$live_site_image = "http://example.net/wp-content/themes/example/images/dog-in-park.jpg";
preg_match('/images\/([^-]+)-/', $live_site_image, $matches);
// $matches[0] will be "dog"
```

`$matches` will get filled with the content matched within each `(...)` in the pattern. In this case there will be one match.
The pattern I used is "images/" followed by 1 or more non-dash characters followed by a dash. I only capture the part that you want.

This is just one way to extract "dog" from your input string,
there may be a better pattern more suitable for your purpose,
depending largely on the other possible urls and parts to extract.